# Showing Newest Questions with only preferred tags

Tags: support

I spend most of my time on Stack Overflow, but I think the process is the same. If not, perhaps somebody could point me in the right question.

I have some preferred tags, and I see that questions including those tags are highlighted. However, they often include tags of no interest to me.

- Is it possible to *exclude* tags?
- Is it possible to hide the other questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Show newest for a few tags

Search has the ability to do this (up to a certain length). For example, you can see all questions tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) by searching [`[feature-request] or [discussion]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+or+discussion).

On Stack Overflow, I use the New Nav to see only the tags I want. It's a bit more flexible and easy to use. (You may need to opt into the New Nav.)

### Hide tags

You can hide questions tagged with your ignored tags.

- Go to *Edit Profile & Settings* > *Preferences*:

  > [image]
- Under "Ignored Tags", add some tags you want to ignore and select "Hide questions in your ignored tags"

  > [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited the ignored tags list, and that has helped. I have also opted in for the New Nav. It’s much better, but I wish I could tell it to exclude questions with other tags.